# Is there a version of Synactis' TPDFViewer in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-xe, viewer

I have used the Synactis product PDF-in-the-box in Delphi 2006 projects and also a free component they had called TPDFViewer, which allows you to embed a PDF viewer in your application.

I am porting one app to XE and - having found that trying to install the TPDFViewer I had in XE did some serious damage to my installation - I'm looking for a replacement.

I have installed XE-supported trial versions of their current offerings PDF-in-the-box 4.04 and All-in-the-box 4.04 but can't see any sign of the TPdfViewer component in either.  Their website FAQ implies this functionality has been replaced by functions to start Adobe Reader.

So I want a (free would be nice, but not essential) PDF viewer for Delphi XE which doesn't just chain to Adobe Reader and allows user interaction or programmatic control over zoom, page number etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried several times to find a good PDF viewer. Most of them were fake components. The best way is to embed acrobat reader dll directly into your application and command it from there.

It was 8 years ago, so I do not remember the code that I used to do this. You import the acroXX.dll file directly into Delphi, it prepares a user component for you and then you install this component directly in to your Component palette.

The worst thing in this configuration is that you have to take care of the acrobat reader dll that is installed on your clients. Any update/upgrade of the reader may cause your application to fail.

Comment: Thanks for that @Ali.  What if we were to get it working with Acroxx.dll and then rename it and keep it private to my app.  Would that solve the problem of Adobe updates breaking my app?

Comment: I am not sure, but the dll may contain only the api to the whole reader component. to be sure immediately copy only the acroxx.dll to a clean installation (w/o Acrobat reader) and give it a try.

Comment: @rossmcm Any feedback as to whether this suggestion worked? I.e. is the dll just a wrapper to the Reader API, or can it render PDFs by itself?

Comment: @DaveBoltman Sorry Dave, I was pulled onto something else more pressing and this got pushed down the queue, where it remains. I can find precious little on the web about using AcroPDF.dll to implement a viewer - nothing for Delphi.

Comment: @rossmcm Thanks for the feedback - appreciated anyways